# Unittest reuse class instance inheriting from dict

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am facing a strange issue where [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) is re-using the same class instance if it is inheriting from a dict.

My actual class does not directly inherit from `dict` but from [MutableMapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) and the behavior is the same.

```
import unittest


class MyClass(dict):
    pass


class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_myclass_1(self):
        mc = MyClass()
        print(id(mc))

    def test_myclass_2(self):
        mc = MyClass()
        print(id(mc))

    def test_myclass_3(self):
        mc = MyClass()
        print(id(mc))

    def test_myclass_4(self):
        mc = MyClass()
        print(id(mc))
```

Then when running this, we can see that the same object instance is re-used:

```
$ python3 -m unittest -v test.py                                                                                                                           
test_myclass_1 (test.TestMyClass) ... 140057337562040
ok
test_myclass_2 (test.TestMyClass) ... 140057337562128
ok
test_myclass_3 (test.TestMyClass) ... 140057337562040
ok
test_myclass_4 (test.TestMyClass) ... 140057337562128
ok
```

What is going on?

Comment: What makes you think it's the same instance? It isn't; Python is just reusing a spare memory location.

Comment: @DanielRoseman In my example the [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) is the same, so there are enormous chances that this is the same object. Also if I set a value in one of the ``MyClass`` instance it shows up in the other test.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot a ``deepcopy`` somewhere. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the python 3 documentation of [**id()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. **Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.**

Your test cases are executed one after another, which means that two instance of MyClass is non-overlapping objects as pointed in documentation the id isn't guaranteed to be unique for such case.

**Good Luck ! :)**